# Spring Hibernate ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, many-to-many

I have 2 tables, VIDEO, VIDEOCATEGORY and joining table VIDEO2VIDEOCATEGORY. 
I am trying to make many to many annotation. There is no error or warning in compilation.

Database is empty in the begining. I try to persist Video entity(with list of VideoCategory)..at this time is all correect. New video is added to database. Some new categories are added as well. Then I try to add new video with new unique categories ...correct as well. Problem is when I try to add new Video with categories already existing in DB. Before this attempt I have 2 record in VIDEO2VIDEOCATEGORY ("cat1", 3) and ("cat2", 3) ...after attemp there should be 2 new records - ("cat1", 4) and ("cat2", 4) and 2 existing ("cat1", 3) and ("cat2", 3) but those old are not in DB. They were rewritten by 2 new records.

How to solve it?
My codes:

```
   import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;


    @Entity
    public class VideoCategory implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -722840296120424003L;

        @Id 
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String id;


        @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
        @JoinTable(name = "video2videocategory",
              joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cat_id")}, inverseJoinColumns =       @JoinColumn(name = "vid_id"))
          private List videos;


        public VideoCategory(){
        }

        public VideoCategory(String id) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        public List getVideos() {
            return videos;
        }
        public void setVideos(List videos) {
            this.videos = videos;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "VideoCategory [id=" + id + ", videos=" + videos + "]";
        }
    }


    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.EnumType;
    import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
    import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;



    @Entity
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="VID_SEQ_GEN",
        sequenceName="VIDSEQ",
        allocationSize=1
    )
    public class Video implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 2284488937952510797L;

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="VID_SEQ_GEN")
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "title", unique = false, nullable = false)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "video_path", unique = false, nullable = false)
        private String videoPath;

        @Column(name = "video_type", unique = false, nullable = false)
        @Enumerated(value=EnumType.STRING) 
        private VideoType videoType;

        @Column(name = "creation_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
        private Date creationDate;

        @ManyToMany
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
         @JoinTable(name = "video2videocategory", 
                 joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "vid_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id"))
        private List categories;



        public Video(){
        }


        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getVideoPath() {
            return videoPath;
        }
        public void setVideoPath(String videoPath) {
            this.videoPath = videoPath;
        }
        public VideoType getVideoType() {
            return videoType;
        }
        public void setVideoType(VideoType videoType) {
            this.videoType = videoType;
        }
        public Date getCreationDate() {
            return creationDate;
        }
        public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
            this.creationDate = creationDate;
        }
        public List getCategories() {
            return categories;
        }

        public void setCategories(List categories) {
            this.categories = categories;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Video [id=" + id + ", creationDate="
                    + creationDate + ", title=" + title
                    + ", videoPath=" + videoPath + ", videoType=" + videoType + "]";
        }
    }
```

I have tried both jpa and hibernate annotations.

Please help.

Comment: Show your `save()` method seems like it is updating it not creating a new one.When you think that you are adding a `new Video` make sure it actually is new instance of video not an existing one. Your mapping is correct issue is either in `save()` or more likely in what you think is a new instance of video where are in reality it is not.

Comment: public void save(Video video) {
  getHibernateTemplate().save(video); 
 }

Comment: I am creating new instance of Video , without id and this I try to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably that you defined the many to many relationship as a parent on both sides.
One side should be the child, like this:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories") // in the class VideoCategory
```